# Unable to locate package php8.1-geoip

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am upgrading a system from PHP 7.4 to 8.1 using as base Ubuntu 22.10.

In the old image, we are using `php7.4-geoip`, but this package doesn't exist in PHP 8.1.

```
apt install php8.1-geoip
```

> Unable to locate package php8.1-geoip

What is the procedure to migrate to a newer version?

Comment: You'll either need to contact the distro's package maintainer and ask that they build/package the extension for 8.1, or build the extension yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package isn't available yet, however you can install via composer.

Ensure GeoIP is installed on the machine:

```
apt install -y geoip-bin geoip-database
geoipupdate -v
```

Install via PHP Composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar require geoip2/geoip2:~2.0
```

Quick test script to ensure it's all working:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$geoip = new Reader('/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
$reader = $geoip->city('12.87.118.0');

echo "I should be United States.... ".$reader->country->name."\n";
```

Output:

```
root@cc19c55aedef:/# php test-geoip.php
I should be United States.... United States
```

Comment: Is this library compatible with the old one without any code change?

Comment: I'm pretty confident GeoIP hasn't changed its interface.