# Install PECL GeoIP for PHP 8.1 ubuntu 22

Tags: php, geoip, phar

I'm trying to use PHP's PECL functions for geoip such as geoip_country_code_by_name(). This obviously needs the Pecl geoip extension.

However, on Ubuntu 22 and for PHP 8.1, this extension doesn't work.

**Approach 1:**

```
apt install php8.1-geoip
```

failed, does not exist

**Approach 2:**

```
pecl install geoip-beta
```

failed, can't compile for php 8.1
make: *** [Makefile:202: geoip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

**Approach 3:** Installing it with phar composer

failed: only uses maxmind's mmdb format, and functions are different. I want to use the older GeoIP.dat files.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

GEOIP has no PHP 8.1 version, you should use Geoip2 to be right,
Please refer to ([Unable to locate package php8.1-geoip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278262/unable-to-locate-package-php8-1-geoip))
(https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php)